# Jquery validate arbitrary HTML elements with custom validation rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I'm using Jquery Validate to validate a form.
I've added a custom validation method via

```
$.validator.addMethod
```

If I add this method to a textbox, the validation will work without problems.

I want this custom validation method to highlight a certain div container that I create via JavaScript.
If I change the following line (inside of "rules" in the  .validate call)

```
"MyTextbox": 
{
  MyMethod: true,
},
```

to use the ID of the div I created via JavaScript, my custom validation rule will be ignored (the other rules will still apply).

I'm struggling to find the corresponding documentation. It seems that I can only add a rule an input element and not to a div.
Am I approaching this the wrong way? How can I add a rule, that appends a message after a certain div-element, if the validation fails?

Comment: _"How can I add a rule, that appends a message after a certain div-element, if the validation fails?"_ ~  Depends... are you validating an `input` element and need help placing the message or are you looking for a way to validate the `div`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two important things...

1)  You ***must*** assign rules by `name` when using the `rules` option within `.validate()`, and every input field must contain a unique `name` attribute no matter how rules are assigned.

2)  **Using this plugin, validation can only be applied to `input`, `textarea`, and `select` elements.  Period.**

Workaround:  You *could* create a `type="hidden"` `input` element for validation and use jQuery to copy the relevant value from your `div` into this hidden field upon a certain triggering event.  [You can then manually trigger validation using something like `$('#myHiddenInput').valid()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid).

---

For precise error message placement, you would use [the `errorPlacement` callback function](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement).  Write a custom function with a conditional for placing the one message.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the two important things ;) I'm now using an input hidden and added an if/else block into errorPlacement =)